# Can matched patterns be used in a replacement string?

Tags: linux, bash, regex, sed

I am new to both regular expressions and GNU sed. I have an anonymised sample of the data below.

```
RED: 13905 16356 17457 18164 18447 21063 26924 27684 30111 30205
CERISE: 6221 6524 18250 24367 24462 29014
CARMINE: 39 49 53 81 95 99 105 106 109 134 195 226 260 350 383 393 397 414 417 435 439 478 488 516 521 535 596 599 614 621 628 630 632 635 785 786 810 836 837 841 852 855 953 1029 1104 1121 1122 1137 1148
VERMILLION: 23029
```

I would like to replace each whitespace, after the first, with the text at the beginning of the string plus a prefix (</>), so that desired output is:

```
RED: 13905</>RED: 16356</>RED: 17457</>RED: 18164</>RED: 18447</>RED: 21063</>RED: 26924</>RED: 27684</>RED: 30111</>RED: 30205
CERISE: 6221</>CERISE: 6524</>CERISE: 18250</>CERISE: 24367</>CERISE: 24462</>CERISE: 29014
CARMINE: 39</>CARMINE: 49</>CARMINE: 53</>CARMINE: 81</>CARMINE: 95</>CARMINE: 99</>CARMINE: 105</>CARMINE: 106</>CARMINE: 109</>CARMINE: 134</>CARMINE: 195</>CARMINE: 226</>CARMINE: 260</>CARMINE: 350</>CARMINE: 383</>CARMINE: 393</>CARMINE: 397</>CARMINE: 414</>CARMINE: 417</>CARMINE: 435</>CARMINE: 439</>CARMINE: 478</>CARMINE: 488</>CARMINE: 516</>CARMINE: 521</>CARMINE: 535</>CARMINE: 596</>CARMINE: 599</>CARMINE: 614</>CARMINE: 621</>CARMINE: 628</>CARMINE: 630</>CARMINE: 632</>CARMINE: 635</>CARMINE: 785</>CARMINE: 786</>CARMINE: 810</>CARMINE: 836</>CARMINE: 837</>CARMINE: 841</>CARMINE: 852</>CARMINE: 855</>CARMINE: 953</>CARMINE: 1029</>CARMINE: 1104</>CARMINE: 1121</>CARMINE: 1122</>CARMINE: 1137</>CARMINE: 1148
VERMILLION: 23029
```

I tried the below, which interpreted ' ^.*: ' literally and did not match the beginning of the line (I ignored the fact that the first space would also be replaced for the timebeing).

```
sed 's/ /\<\\\>^.*: /g' inputfile

RED:<\>^.*: 13905<\>^.*: 16356<\>^.*: 17457<\>^.*: 18164<\>^.*: 18447<\>^.*: 21063<\>^.*: 26924<\>^.*: 27684<\>^.*: 30111<\>^.*: 30205
CERISE:<\>^.*: 6221<\>^.*: 6524<\>^.*: 18250<\>^.*: 24367<\>^.*: 24462<\>^.*: 29014
CARMINE:<\>^.*: 39<\>^.*: 49<\>^.*: 53<\>^.*: 81<\>^.*: 95<\>^.*: 99<\>^.*: 105<\>^.*: 106<\>^.*: 109<\>^.*: 134<\>^.*: 195<\>^.*: 226<\>^.*: 260<\>^.*: 350<\>^.*: 383<\>^.*: 393<\>^.*: 397<\>^.*: 414<\>^.*: 417<\>^.*: 435<\>^.*: 439<\>^.*: 478<\>^.*: 488<\>^.*: 516<\>^.*: 521<\>^.*: 535<\>^.*: 596<\>^.*: 599<\>^.*: 614<\>^.*: 621<\>^.*: 628<\>^.*: 630<\>^.*: 632<\>^.*: 635<\>^.*: 785<\>^.*: 786<\>^.*: 810<\>^.*: 836<\>^.*: 837<\>^.*: 841<\>^.*: 852<\>^.*: 855<\>^.*: 953<\>^.*: 1029<\>^.*: 1104<\>^.*: 1121<\>^.*: 1122<\>^.*: 1137<\>^.*: 1148<\>^.*: 
VERMILLION:<\>^.*: 23029
```

**So is it that regular expressions cannot be used in a replacement string?** What other way can I do this?

Thanks,
L

Comment: I am new to terminology... If you have a suggestion on better naming this question please say

Comment: Are you open to a perl solution?

Comment: I did wonder if this would be beyond sed capabilities? I haven't used perl much, but sure :)

Answer (score 5):

Use repeated substitution:

```
sed -E ':a; s/^(([A-Z:]+).*)([0-9]+) /\1\3<\/>\2 /; ta'
```

Output:

```
RED: 13905</>RED: 16356</>RED: 17457</>RED: 18164</>RED: 18447</>RED: 21063</>RED: 26924</>RED: 27684</>RED: 30111</>RED: 30205
CERISE: 6221</>CERISE: 6524</>CERISE: 18250</>CERISE: 24367</>CERISE: 24462</>CERISE: 29014
CARMINE: 39</>CARMINE: 49</>CARMINE: 53</>CARMINE: 81</>CARMINE: 95</>CARMINE: 99</>CARMINE: 105</>CARMINE: 106</>CARMINE: 109</>CARMINE: 134</>CARMINE: 195</>CARMINE: 226</>CARMINE: 260</>CARMINE: 350</>CARMINE: 383</>CARMINE: 393</>CARMINE: 397</>CARMINE: 414</>CARMINE: 417</>CARMINE: 435</>CARMINE: 439</>CARMINE: 478</>CARMINE: 488</>CARMINE: 516</>CARMINE: 521</>CARMINE: 535</>CARMINE: 596</>CARMINE: 599</>CARMINE: 614</>CARMINE: 621</>CARMINE: 628</>CARMINE: 630</>CARMINE: 632</>CARMINE: 635</>CARMINE: 785</>CARMINE: 786</>CARMINE: 810</>CARMINE: 836</>CARMINE: 837</>CARMINE: 841</>CARMINE: 852</>CARMINE: 855</>CARMINE: 953</>CARMINE: 1029</>CARMINE: 1104</>CARMINE: 1121</>CARMINE: 1122</>CARMINE: 1137</>CARMINE: 1148
VERMILLION: 23029
```

Commented version:

```
# Create a label we can jump to
:a

# This pattern will capture the front heading into group \2 and
# everything following that up-to number+space into group \1.
# The matched number is saved in group \3
s/^(([A-Z:]+).*)([0-9]+) /\1\3<\/>\2 /

# If the previous substitution was successful, repeat it
ta
```

Comment: Maybe you should add the explanation that it works (from the end to the beginning) because after the substitution, the last edition replaced "number followed by space" by "number followed by a smaller-than symbol". Otherwise great solution, very clever. Kudos!

Answer (score 2):

Here is a perl solution:

```
perl -ane '@_=split/ /,$_;$x=shift@_;print "$x ",join "</>$x ",@_;' inputfile
RED: 13905</>RED: 16356</>RED: 17457</>RED: 18164</>RED: 18447</>RED: 21063</>RED: 26924</>RED: 27684</>RED: 30111</>RED: 30205
CERISE: 6221</>CERISE: 6524</>CERISE: 18250</>CERISE: 24367</>CERISE: 24462</>CERISE: 29014
CARMINE: 39</>CARMINE: 49</>CARMINE: 53</>CARMINE: 81</>CARMINE: 95</>CARMINE: 99</>CARMINE: 105</>CARMINE: 106</>CARMINE: 109</>CARMINE: 134</>CARMINE: 195</>CARMINE: 226</>CARMINE: 260</>CARMINE: 350</>CARMINE: 383</>CARMINE: 393</>CARMINE: 397</>CARMINE: 414</>CARMINE: 417</>CARMINE: 435</>CARMINE: 439</>CARMINE: 478</>CARMINE: 488</>CARMINE: 516</>CARMINE: 521</>CARMINE: 535</>CARMINE: 596</>CARMINE: 599</>CARMINE: 614</>CARMINE: 621</>CARMINE: 628</>CARMINE: 630</>CARMINE: 632</>CARMINE: 635</>CARMINE: 785</>CARMINE: 786</>CARMINE: 810</>CARMINE: 836</>CARMINE: 837</>CARMINE: 841</>CARMINE: 852</>CARMINE: 855</>CARMINE: 953</>CARMINE: 1029</>CARMINE: 1104</>CARMINE: 1121</>CARMINE: 1122</>CARMINE: 1137</>CARMINE: 1148
VERMILLION: 23029
```

With redirection to outputfile:

```
perl -ane '@_=split/ /,$_;$x=shift@_;print "$x ",join "</>$x ",@_;' inputfile > outpufile
```

**Explanation:**

```
@_=split/ /,$_;         # split each line on space
$x=shift@_;             # remove the first element (i.e. "RED: ") and store it in variable $x
print                   # print on STDOUT
"$x "                   # value of $x and a space
,
join "</>$x ",@_        # all values of @_ joined with </> and content of $x
```

Answer (score 1):

**Disclaimer**: I am no mathematician, and my answer should be read from a practical point of view, not a formal one. Should you have any formal corrections or additions to issue, please edit or comment my answer. I would be happy to learn something.

---

To answer your question, no, regular expressions cannot be used in the substitution definition (or "replacement string"); only back-references can.

As a short note about your comment regarding if this is *"beyond sed capabilities"*, it is beyond strict regular expressions's capabilities, but not sed's. Read on to see why.

---

Now, to solve your problem, strictly speaking, you cannot use regular expressions only. Regular expressions are using [regular grammar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_grammar) to define the desired processing, and your input isn't possible to parse with a regular grammar. Indeed, as explained on the Wikipedia link, a regular grammar only allows processing to be composed of three different transformations:

- Non-terminal symbol → terminal symbol
- Non-terminal symbol → terminal symbol and non-terminal symbol
- Non-terminal symbol → empty-string

So, the part of your processing requiring each "word" your input to be prefixed with `</>` is possible with regular expressions, as it can easily be expressed (in `sed` vernacular, using extended syntax) with `s,\w+ ,&</>,g`. This is simple and straightforward. Note that the output is reusing the input *verbatim*, and therefore, the space following the word is also in the output. If you wanted to remove this, you would have to do it in a subsequent transformation (so, subsequent regular expression).

However, the part of your processing requiring the first word to be stored in memory, and be prefixed not to the second, but to each subsequent word, cannot be expressed using regular expressions. For this, you need a [turing complete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_completeness) language, because you need both conditional branching (is the current word beyond the second one?) and to change an arbitrary amount of memory (store the first word in memory for future use). *Note that this last requirement isn't strictly needed, as illustrated by the other solutions: tricks can be used to avoid it, and use only loops.*

You can implement a solution to your problem in pretty much any turing-complete language (including `sed`, as [it has support for `loop` statements, and has a temporary buffer](https://catonmat.net/proof-that-sed-is-turing-complete)), and I would recommend `awk` if you need or want to keep things simple (and POSIX).

Here is my awk solution:

```
{ printf "%s %s", $1, $2; for (i=3; i <= NF; i++) printf "</>%s %s", $1, $i; printf "\n" }
```

*N.B.: This solution is meant to be easy to read and understand, but it does not exactly transform the input into the corresponding output perfectly: if a newline is missing at the end of the input, the output will have one anyway. See the other solutions if that is a problem for you.*